how can i write className with function in react js
I am new to ReactJS and JSX and I am having a little problem with the code below.
I am trying to add multiple ways to the className attribute
<ul className="iqacbar-nav" id="iqacbar-nav">
<li className="nav-heading">menu</li>
<li className={isActive('/')} "nav-item">
 <Link className="nav-link collapsed active" to="/>
  <span> Home</span>
 </Link>    
</li>
<li className="nav-heading">aboutus</li>
<li className="nav-heading">contactus</li>
<li className="nav-heading">admissions</li>
<li className="nav-heading">courses</li>
<li className="nav-heading">blogs</li>
<li className="nav-heading">reviews</li>
</ul>
 `please correct this`


Can u please explain your question in more detail? currently it doesn't have proper explanation.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


About the Problem
If I am getting it right, you want dynamic ways to add classes in JSX.


Solution

There can be multiple way to add dynamic classes like



Use of Ternary Operator



 className={isActive('/') ? "hey" : ""};

//if  isActive returns true then classname will be `hey` otherwise "".





Use of Functions


className={isActive('/')};

function isActive(val){
if(val==="/")return "hey";
return "otherclasses";

}



Feel free to comment if you face any further issues


as I understand you want to change the className value based on the condition isActive('/') what you can do is:
<li className={isActive('/')? "nav-item" : ""}>

Assuming isActive function is returning a boolean. Using this form which called ternary operation (single line if statement) you can tell react that if isActive return true then use the first value (nav-item) if not use the second value (empty string).

If you want to change styles based on some conditions, I would recommend to use some kind of a tool for constructing classNames strings conditionally, e.x. clsx.
In the example below you can see that I'm changing div background color based on isTurnedOff state value. You can add as many conditions to clsx() function as you want.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';

const Bulb = () => {
  const [isTurnedOff, setIsTurnedOff] = useState<boolean>(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className={clsx(
          'h-10 w-10',
          isTurnedOff ? 'bg-gray-300' : 'bg-yellow-400',
        )}
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setIsTurnedOff(!isTurnedOff)}>
        {isTurnedOff ? 'Turn on' : 'Turn off'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Bulb;

